# JavaScript May Be Interfering with CSS 3-Level Navigation System

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This fiddle works (see `We Distribute` under Products):

http://jsfiddle.net/dgUFw/1362/

But on the page in the context of the website I'm building, I have JavaScript running (including jQuery).  There is a slideshow on the home page, for example, and when I hover the 3rd level of the fiddle navigation, it goes away after a second or two.  Plus, there are other weird behaviors I can't explain, like the 3rd level `li` moving to be on top of the 2nd level list, etc, where this doesn't occur in the fiddle.

I'm relatively new to integrating CSS and JavaScript together, so I have not seen this behavior.

When I turned off JavaScript in Firefox, the behavior seemed to subside.

What is causing this and how can I fix it?  I tried different JS libraries and CSS normalization on `jsfiddle.net` as well, and the results were the same.  I also tried Opera with same fiddle results and worse website results.  Chrome seems to be more robust and less prone to mis-behaving.

You may have noticed also that when inside the 3rd level, the 2nd level `We Distribute` text is black.  I'm also having difficulty getting this to remain white.  But this isn't my primary question here.  I'm most interested in the JavaScript/CSS interactions.

**EDIT NOTE**

I took some advice from below and tested this more:

I did some more testing on the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nicorellius/dgUFw/1368/  I found that if you click "We Distribute" the menu collapses on itself.  This is actually similar behavior to what I'm seeing on the website, except the collapse occurs without clicking.  After clicking the menu and it collapses, then hover doesn't bring it back to normal, which I would expect it would.

Comment: If I include jQuery on that fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/stevegreatrex/dgUFw/1363/) then the menu still works as I would expect.  What are you seeing?

Comment: I tried that too and I'm seeing the same as you.  What I'm seeing is described above.  On the website (not the fiddle), the menu behaves differently until I disabled JS in the browser.

Comment: It does really vanish after a second without moving the mouse? Because there is a little space between the button and the dropdown and therefor its not working very good.

Comment: The testing I've done multiple times is to carefully hover as many aspects as I can in the fiddle and then repeat behavior on webpage.  In the case of the webpage, yes, I simply hover to where I want, and let my hand off the mouse and after 1-3 seconds it disappears. Weird...  This behavior goes away when I disable JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

First, I think your problem with the menu disappearing is due to z-index. The slideshow probably has a higher, or the same, z-index, causing the menu to lose its hover state. To fix this:

```
#nav-top li, #nav-top li a {
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Second, for your color/hover issues, you need to change up your CSS a bit:

```
#nav-top li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

#nav-top li#products-sub:hover > a, #nav-top li#home-sub:hover > a,
#nav-top li#faq-sub:hover > a, #nav-top li#user-sub:hover > a, #nav-top li ul.dist-sub:hover  {
    color: #fff;
}
```

This will keep the hover-state of the li and set the color of the link based on that rather than the link.

Fiddle with the changes: http://jsfiddle.net/dgUFw/1364/

Comment: Thanks for answer! The color issue was fixed with your recommendation, so I definitely gave you +1.  But the z-index fix doesn't seem to be working.  I will double check and make sure...

Comment: If the z-index doesn't fix it, you may have to give a better example or a link with the page, it's hard to say what could be causing it without really seeing what's going on.

Comment: I agree.  I was hoping to find a fix without doing that, but I may have too...  Thanks for your feedback; I appreciate it.

Comment: Could you set up a sample slider in jsfiddle the same way you have it set up on your site?

Comment: The second bit of code is much more explicit than necessary. `#nav-top li:hover > a` is more than likely sufficient.

Comment: I might be able to set up a more accurate fiddle or I might just upload to test server and show here.  I need to decide.

Comment: I did some more testing on the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nicorellius/dgUFw/1368/  I found that if you click "We Distribute" the menu collapses on itself.  This is actually similar behavior to what I'm seeing on the website, except the collapse occurs without clicking.  After clicking the menu and it collapses, then hover doesn't bring it back to normal, which I would expect it would.

Comment: Hm. When I click on "We Distribute" it acts as a link normally would.

Comment: @Samsquanch, can we chat real quick?

Comment: @Samsquanch, what OS are you using?  I could be bumping into a Linux Firefox phenomenon.  The behavior is most sever with Opera, and least severe with Chrome.  I'm going to find a Windows machine...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21483/discussion-between-nicorellius-and-samsquanch)